# How to reinstall conjure-up?

Tags: lxc, conjure-up, kubernetes

After trying to get a local kubernetes cluster running with `conjure-up kubernets-core` on Ubuntu 16.04.3, I wanted to reinstall everything and start over from scratch since my configuration did not succeed.

Basically killing juju applications and doing `snap remove conjure-up` and `snap remove lxd`.
Once again I installed it with `snap install conjure-up --classic`. But now `conjure-up kubernetes-core` only displays "aws" in cloud list options, no other clouds and no localhost option that was there on first install. Also nothing happens when trying to proceed with "aws".

I've tried removing all caches and configuations that I can find, such as ~/.cache, ~/.config, ~/.local without success.

What's the proper way to really purge and re-install this?

**edit**

I scrapped the conjure-up/juju/lxd and went for kubeadm instead. It was a much simpler approach for a local cluster with less dependencies, configuration and overhead.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, another way to get a local Kubernetes cluster running easily is with microk8s from the Kubernetes team at Canonical (https://microk8s.io/).

> Fast Install - Get a full Upstream Kubernetes system running in under
>   60 seconds
>
> Safe and Secure - Runs safely on your laptop with state of the art
>   isolation.
>
> Pure Upstream - Binaries directly from the source, delivered to you
>   laptop and configured in seconds!